# After I log in in Ubuntu I get a black screen and cannot access anything. I am using ubuntu with Vmware

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, screen, vmware

I have a text file that I wrote something in it and I would be really happy to get it back. It was a "transcript" of the videos I was watching to teach myselft Ubuntu. It was quite a lot and I would really like to get it back and that is why I need to fix this issue rather than installing another copy.

Whenever I log in I get to the log in screen, input my password and then the screen goes black (it first looks like in the past with the big CRT Tvs when you connected your SEGA console and then goes black). I cannot access anything. I am not saying that what I tried so far is exhaustive, there might be ways to open the terminal that I don't know (I'm a Noob). I don't know what other info may be useful. Please let me know if I need to add anything else.

I started having this problem after I bought a monitor and connected it to my laptop.

Thank you!

Edit: I managed to get this print screen: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA866.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect the second monitor and restart the system? And are you using a dual boot or a Virtual Machine? Also, what kind of laptop do you have?

Comment: I tried disconnecting the monitor and it still did not work. I am using a virtual machine (VMWare) the laptop is a lenovo G500 Thanks!